# Substituting in string variables in http post request payload

Tags: post, python-requests

I'm iterating over a for loop of a list of ingredients (strings) calling a http post request for each one to obtain their nutritional info.

The following works.

```
data = '{"query": "black olives"}'
r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)
body = json.loads(r.text)
```

But this:

```
for ingredient in ingredients:
    data = '{"query": ' + ingredient + '}'
    r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)
    body = json.loads(r.text)
```

gives the error:

```
{'message': 'Unexpected token r in JSON at position 10'}
```

How do I fix it?

**Edit:** It works now.

Comment: data is no JSON : *data = '{"query": ' + ingredient + '}'*, can you show *r.text* ?

Comment: Could you please provide the `url` variable

Comment: print(r.text) and print(body) return {"message":"Unexpected token r in JSON at position 10"} and {'message': 'Unexpected token r in JSON at position 10'} respectively.

Comment: quotes are missing, use: *data = '{"query": "' + ingredient + '"}'*

Comment: @user2413548 Ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to construct JSON from a dict.

Try this:

```
import json

for ingredient in ingredients:
    data = {"query": ingredient}
    # Two options : let requests do the json conversion of the dict
    r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, json=data)
    # or do it yourself
    # r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    body = json.loads(r.text)
```